# React router breaks index.html scripts

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

When I get under a subdirectory in react router index.html links and scripts fail to load.

```
:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/solutions/css/default.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

When i'm in /foo routes, its fine.. But when I get under /foo/foo, I get this error. This route for example is /solutions/home. In the console error it get to /solutions and then from there tries to import scrs from index.html..  Am i missing something?

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" sizes="16x16" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"
    />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/component.css" />
    <title>Neuroelectrics</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an easy one.. after thinking and trying to debug a lot about React and React router, I realized that it was nothing with it (dumb), just added %PUBLIC_URL% to all linking files. The problem was that with react router index.html was trying to fetch these files under the router routes.